# PHP - string vs array comparison

Tags: php

I'll post a question and I hope the administrators stackoverflow do not put this as a duplicate topic , because I find no explanation for such a thing .

All we know that after the type- juggling this comparison looks like this:

```
false == array() -> (bool) == false (bool) array() -> false == false -> true
```

So far, nothing unusual.

The problem was trying to ask for an explanation for such a thing but the answers did not have senses and then it seemed that the topic was duplicated , but actually it is not a duplicate topic.

The question was how the php interprets this comparison below:

```
'' == array()
```

Some people said:

"A cast is done to the empty string to array"

The result is:
 
    (array) '' == array() -> array('') == array() -> false

Seems to be right.

But the big problem is here, below:

```
'' == array('')
```

Because it does not return true ? If by some theory:

`'' == array('')` -> This should return true

`'' == array('')` -> `(array)'' == array('') -> array('') == array('')`

But false is returned.

Can you explain once and for all this issue ?

Comment: When an array is compared to a string, the array is greater.  (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types)

Comment: In short: __garbage in - garbage out__ You should decide first, why you need to compare arrays and strings. I'm 99% sure, that in normal situation you will always compare entities of __same type__

Comment: Jonny, can u explain ?

Comment: Oops, that was the wrong language link, here again the right one: [PHP type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: @user3151657 My logic says, a bag can contain apples `var_dump(array() > "");`, but an apple no bags `var_dump("" > array());` And an `array("")` even contains a string `var_dump(array("") > "");` like a bag with an apple :D

Comment: I am curious and like a scientific explanation and not a logical explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr no casting is performed in the comparison:

Internally the comparison is done via [`compare_function`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_operators.c#1402), which is called when the parser sees a `==` operator.

Inside this function a test is done based on the type of each operand; the combination of string and array doesn't have a specific behaviour, so a numeric conversion is attempted [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_operators.c#1545).

This attempt fails for both operands, because an empty string is not numeric and an array isn't either. It then performs another test [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_operators.c#1549) to check whether any operand is an array or an object. If so, it either returns -1 or 1, depending on which operand matched.

Of course, this is also documented in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types) to help those who don't want to decipher the source code :)

Comment: I thought there was rules for all possible types of comparison. What I did understand was that it was always made ​​made ​​one cast to the type of variable that had more weight. But I liked that explanation.